# How to scrape product data from https://www.jumia.ma/pc-portables/

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a problem getting the src of img and a tags using jsoup on a spring project , Im getting  instead '1', '5', 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7'

Here is the code:

```java
String url1 = "https://www.jumia.ma/pc-portables/";
Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(url1).get();
 
//List de noms et prix produits et le src des images :
List<Element> noms1 = doc1.getElementsByClass("name");
List<Element> prix1 = doc1.getElementsByClass("prc");
List<Element> images1 = doc1.select("img");
 
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    if (!noms1.get(i).ownText().isEmpty() && !prix1.get(i).ownText().isEmpty()) {
        Produit p = new Produit();
        p.setNom(noms1.get(i).ownText());
        p.setPrix(prix1.get(i).ownText());
        p.setImage(images1.get(i).attr("abs:src"));
        p.setUrl("https://www.jumia.ma/pc-portables/");
        p.setIdcategorie(5);
        produitRepository.save(p);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These queries are simply too broad for your use case:

```java
List<Element> noms1 = doc1.getElementsByClass("name");
List<Element> prix1 = doc1.getElementsByClass("prc");
List<Element> images1 = doc1.select("img");
```

You can always print your query results and see for yourself. For example:

```java
List<Element> noms1 = doc1.getElementsByClass("name");
System.out.println(noms1);
```

---

You should split up your query into two steps. First, select the container with the item list, then process each item. Try this:

```java
String url = "https://www.jumia.ma/pc-portables/";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element catalog = doc.selectFirst("[data-catalog]");
for (Element item : catalog.select("article")) {
    // name
    System.out.println(item.select(".info > .name").text());
    // price
    System.out.println(item.select(".info > .prc").text());
    // image
    System.out.println(item.selectFirst(".img-c > img").attr("data-src"));
}
```

Note that this only parses the item data from on the first page. If you want to scrape additional pages, repeat the process by using a different url. For example, here is the url that loads the second page:

```
https://www.jumia.ma/pc-portables/?page=2#catalog-listing
```